# adding mysql_real_escape_string automatically with regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-replace, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a mysql class which has a method called `query()` which is basically `mysql_query()`. This method receives the query as the parameter like this:

`insert into table set field1 = 'value 1', field2 = 'value 2'`
or
`select id from table where field1 = 'value 1', field2 like '%value 2%'`

This is not a very good practice, of course, because all the values should be first passed through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

I want to use a regular expression to catch all the patterns where some information is passed to the method, like the bolded sections:

`insert into table set field1 = '**value 1**', field2 = '**value 2**'`.

The problem is that if I let preg_replace be greedy it would eventually catch:

`insert into table set field1 = '**value 1', field2 = 'value 2**'`

and if it's not greedy it would catch:

`insert into table set field1 = '**value **' 1', field2 = 'value 2'` (where filed1 is actually = "value '1".

An option would be to put the values between a delimiter like in the following example, but this does not seem the best method to me:

`insert into table set field1 = {{value 1}}, field2 = {{value 2}}`
and then just catch all text between "{{" and "}}" and replace it with its `mysql_real_escape_string()`'ed value.

Is there a way to do this in a more **professional** way?

ps: sorry for having ** inside the code, I don't know how to bold inside the ticks

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea, because if you were to use }} then now you'll have to escape for the closing }}. You're basically inventing a new syntax to do the exact same thing.

use prepared statements instead.